# Многотабличный запрос MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 4 таблицы, мне нужно выбрать всех пользователей(users) со всеми воронками(funnels) которые у них есть. То есть у одного юзера есть несколько воронок.

```
users | leads      | landings  | funnels
----- | -----      | --------  | -------
id    | id         | id        | id
name  | user_id    | funnel_id | name
      | landing_id |
```

Пример что хочу получить:

```
User name | Funnel name
user 1    | Funnel 1
user 1    | Funnel 2
user 2    | Funnel 1
user 3    | Funnel 2
```

Писал такой запрос но результат оказался не тем:
Получил нужно информацию, но она продублировалась много раз(ровнялось количеству записей в таблицу leads)

```
SELECT users.name,funnels.name
FROM users
    LEFT JOIN leads ON users.id = leads.user_id
        INNER JOIN landings ON leads.landing_id = landings.id
            RIGHT JOIN funnels ON landings.funnel_id = funnels.id
```

Comment: Если у вас проблема только  дублями напишите `SELECT DISTINCT....` или же группируйте `GROUP BY funnels.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будьте проще.

```
SELECT [DISTINCT]
       users.name,
       funnels.name
FROM users,
     leads,
     landings,
     funnels 
WHERE users.id = leads.user_id
  AND leads.landing_id = landings.id
  AND landings.funnel_id = funnels.id
```

Comment: Спасибо, так и вправду намного проще, я сейчас в поисках книги по MySQL, не могли бы вы подсказать, какую выбрать, что бы подтянуть свои знания?

Comment: @АлексейШкурдадо Практика. Плюс форумы - смотришь исходное (выбирай то, что кажется решаемым), стараешься решить, не получается - читаешь первую подсказку... И запоминай приёмы.

Answer (score 1):

Везде нужно писать `LEFT JOIN`. А чтобы убрать дубликаты, добавить `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  users.name,
  funnels.name
FROM
  users
  LEFT JOIN leads ON users.id = leads.user_id
  LEFT JOIN landings ON leads.landing_id = landings.id
  LEFT JOIN funnels ON landings.funnel_id = funnels.id
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. DISTINCT, помог решить мою проблему, но если везде написать Left join то у меня появляются пользователи у которых нету воронок(значение в колонке null)

Comment: Тогда вам нужно вместо `LEFT JOIN` писать `JOIN`